# How to store values in array inside loop?

Tags: labview

I have loop where N=50. inside the loop I have array (vector). my condition is: if i mod 10 == 0, then saving value of summation in a vector. So after finish the loop we expecting to have 5 values stored in a vector. How can I do that without storing all 50 values.

**My Example:
my vector will save (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 0 0 ...). I just want to save only 20 in the first row then repeat it 5 times. I have to use N=50 not 5. is that possible?**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy with [shift registers](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvconcepts/shift_registers_concepts/): use one to pass the array being built from one iteration to the other, and test the `i%10==0` in a case structure. On `true` append the current value to the array, else don't modify it.

[image: VI snippet]

Comment: please see my example. how to implement shift register in my example above.

Comment: right-click on loop's output tunnel, it's in contextual menu. then  the "concatenate/append" node that you currently have after the case, put it inside case.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i understand your question.  With your current condition, i==10, you will only have one value stored in the vector not 5 (ie only the value 10 will be store in the vector).

If you want to save the number every time i is a multiple of 10 then all you need to do is add a condition inside the loop to check whether i mod 10 == 0. If the result is true then add i to the vector otherwise ignore the value of i .  Alternatively you could loop from 1 to 5 times and add i * 10 to your vector. the result will be the same.

Comment: I add example above.you said "If the result is true then add i to the vector otherwise ignore the value of i " how can I ignore value of i and not saving i in the vector.

Comment: You could always leave the vector as is.  That is what is meant by ignoring the value